# NodeJS: Use a pug template to display results

Tags: node.js, express, pug, router

I have a method in a NodeJS app that handles scraping a URL, and when successful, saving that data in a Mongo database, and showing the results.

Main method:

```js
//url parameter
app.get('/urls/', function(req, res) {

  var client = new MetaInspector(req.query.url, {
    timeout: 5000
  });

  client.on("fetch", function() {

    var imagesArray = [];
    var keywordsArray = [];
    var now = new Date();
    var dateVal = dateFormat(now, "mm/dd/yyyy h:MM:ss");


    for (var i = 0; i < client.images.length; i++) {
      // we only want jpgs. nothing else.
      if (client.images[i].indexOf('.jpg') > -1) {
        imagesArray.push({
          "image": client.images[i]
        })
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < client.keywords.length; i++) {
      keywordsArray.push({
        "keyword": client.keywords[i]
      })
    }

    var newUrls = Urls({
      url: client.url,
      date_added: dateVal,
      keywords: req.body.keywords,
      author: client.author,
      description: client.description,
      ogTitle: client.ogTitle,
      ogDescription: client.ogDescription,
      image: client.image,
      images: imagesArray,
      keywords: keywordsArray
    });

    newUrls.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.send('Success' + newUrls);
    });

  });

  client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  client.fetch();

});
```

This all works well and good. But I'm using Pug and Express and have specific routes setup. I'd like instead of sending the newUrls obj to the res.send, have it go to a particular route and pass it to a particular pug template I already have setup:

```js
// Route.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Urls = require('../models/urlModel');
var Footer = require('../models/footerModel');

/* URL Saved Success Page */
router.get('/saved', function (req, res) {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

My view lives in a pug file located at:

/views/saved.pug

```html
div#body

include nav.pug

div.container.item-container
    div.row
    div.col-md-8
        h1 Item successfully saved.
        h5 {item}
        h6 {description}
```

I've tried using the res.send method, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `res.render()`?

Comment: res.render() renders the data, but I want it to get the templating I've setup for other pages using router. Is there a way to use res.render with existing templating?

Comment: I thought you said you already have the template created, where is the template? I am not 100% clear on your question, but you can also use the pug api as needed.

Comment: The template is in in a /views folder. I've added it to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, you want the request redirected to `/saved` with payload after urls saved to database, in this scenario, you could user `res.redirect` with query string

```
newUrls.save(function(err){
    var payload = JSON.stringify({
        url: client.url,
        date_added: dateVal,
        keywords: req.body.keywords,
        author: client.author,
        description: client.description,
        ogTitle: client.ogTitle,
        ogDescription: client.ogDescription,
        image: client.image,
        images: imagesArray,
        keywords: keywordsArray
    })

    //append the payload as a query string
    res.redirect(`/saved?payload=${payload}`)
})
```

and in `/saved` route, you could parse the query and use `res.render`

```
router.get('/saved', function (req, res) {});
    let payload = JSON.parse(req.query.payload);
    if(payload){
        res.render('saved', payload)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Does the payload need to be delivered via the URL parameter, or can it be passed another way? I have a lot of data in the payload, and it would be cleaner if it could be passed to the route in a cleaner way.

Comment: `res.redirect` doesn't support redirect with context data, query string is the only way I could find. Why you don't call `res.render('saved')` directly within `/urls`?

Comment: I'd like the page to use the site template from Pug. Is there another way to apply a pug template to res.render?